# Hive SQL: Other ways to delete rows with a similar ID

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I've a table with several columns. Here's an example (with less columns):

```
PROTOCOL   LINE_FORMAT   SERVICE    MSISDN   
c3p0       solid         cyborg     639275487638
r2r2       rounded       amech      639124512070
c3pX       etc..         etc..      639275487638
bxSer      hard          comm       639200020006
```

Now, MSISDN has occurred twice. Supposedly, the results should only contain one unique MSISDN, regardless of the other data - though that doesn't mean the other data aren't needed.

**Here's what I tried:**

```
SELECT max(PROTOCOL), max(LINE_FORMAT), max(NEURALITIC), max(OP_SERVICE1), max(OP_SERVICE2), max(OP_SERVICE3), max(DATESTAMP), max(APP_NAME), max(IMSI), MSISDN, max(OP_ID), max(OP_LOCATION_ID), max(ROAMER_FLAG), max(TAC), max(LOCATION_LAYER1), max(LOCATION_LAYER2), max(LOCATION_LAYER3), max(LOCATION_LAYER4), max(LOCATION_LAYER5), max(SGSN), max(GGSN), max(APN), max(WEBDOMAIN), max(PROBE_NAME), max(FILE_ID), max(RAT), max(OUT_BYTES), min(IN_BYTES), max(TRANSACTION_COUNT) 
FROM june21dataloader WHERE NEURALITIC LIKE "%Application Usage%" AND WEBDOMAIN LIKE "%bpiexpressonline.com%" GROUP BY MSISDN;
```

Now, when I tried that, I'm pretty sure I got unique mobtels - that's because of the 20 million rows of the original, it only returned 2900 or so.

Troubling, when the projected output is at *least* 6k++

Something's fishy here. Is there something wrong with my query? What would happen if I drop the max()'s?

Now, my question is, what are other ways of doing this job? As far as I tried, `DISTINCT` doesn't seem to work on a single column only, while `GROUP BY` keeps on asking for all the column names (and I'm not even sure if it will produce a unique MSISDN).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MSISDN ORDER BY <CreatedDateOrSomething>) AS Rank
    FROM <Your_Table>) AS SUBQUERY
WHERE Rank = 1
```

This will give you one entry for each MSISDN. The rest of the columns will be the data of the entry with the smallest CreatedDateOrSomething

But if the other data really doesn't matter, then why you don't just do

```
SELECT DISTINCT(MSISDN) FROM <Your_Table>
```

?

Comment: Because they're still important, just not as important as getting only one MSISDN. Sorry for the lack of clarity, I edited the question a bit. I'm not familiar with rank / partition - do I simply change the <CreatedDateorSomething> to something, and expect it to work?

Comment: Yes could replace CreatedDateOrSomething by any other column of your table, because you don't matter which row of the duplicates to see. This query enumerates all duplicates. So if you have three entries with the same MSISDN then the rows will have the rank 1, 2 and 3. Afterwards you just select all rows with the Rank = 1. That leads to the duplicates not be shown anymore.

Comment: That's genius. I'll give it a whirl. Where do I add the filters `NEURALITIC` and `WEBDOMAIN`? Inside the closing parenthesis, after `FROM <Your_Table>`?

Comment: Hive SQL is in the title. :) I'll give it a shot just the same.

Comment: Sorry guy, just realized the solution I posted here is only working in MS SQL Server. I'm trying to check out how the syntax for hive is.

Comment: OK looking at this page [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/taylor22/entry/hive_0_11_may_15), says it should work the same way for Hive SQL. Did you already try it?

Comment: Tried it. Says missing EOF at 'SUBQUERY' near 'AS'. This would be the rest of my query: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MSISDN ORDER BY DATESTAMP) AS Rank FROM june21dataloader WHERE NEURALITIC LIKE "%Application Usage%" AND WEBDOMAIN LIKE "%bpiexpressonline.com%") AS SUBQUERY WHERE Rank = 1;`

Comment: Try to remove _AS_ FROM _AS SUBQUERY_

Comment: Tried that already as well, actually. `I got a Failed to breakup Windowing invocation into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns.` I'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: That's strang. Is the subquery on its own working? If not, is it working without the `WHERE NEURALITIC LIKE "%Application Usage%" AND WEBDOMAIN LIKE "%bpiexpressonline.com%"`

Comment: `SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MSISDN ORDER BY DATESTAMP) AS Rank FROM june21dataloader` displays the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the version of your Hive database?

Comment: I found another possible solution why the query isn't working here [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5038) . Try to write _RANK()_ as _rank()_

Comment: Using the lowercase rank() made the subquery work, thanks. Adding it to the rest of the query, gets me an error that tells me the query is inputting 31 rows, while the table only has 29.